# Probability puzzle for a fair die

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, martingales

What is the expected number of times we have to roll a fair six-sided die to obtain that the number of times any two faces appear are equal (after the first rolling)?

Comment: It is not quite clear if you mean the same in the title as in the body : I interpret this to continue throwing unitl $1,2,3,4,5,6$ all occured the same number of times. Is that what you intent ?

Comment: Do you expect that number of times to be finite with probability $1$? Why? And even if it is (I don't think so), why do you think the expectation is finite?

Comment: @Peter I just changed the title (which should have been a very short summary to give a flavour about this question). By the way, yes, I mean that "continue throwing until 1,2,3,4,5,6 all occurred the same number of times."

Comment: @ProfessorVector No, I do not expect to be finite with probability $1$, and if it is not finite, I expect an answer with a (short and possibly elegant) proof regarding this result. I posed a question about an expectation, which (in general) can be either finite or not finite, as it is obvious. Why do you think I believe that this expectation is finite?

Comment: You expect a proof from others, even though you didn't say why *you* find that problem interesting and what you have thought about it?

Comment: @ProfessorVector There are many ways to prove a statement like this one. Having a simple answer for this puzzle could be interesting for many students, because it can be generalized in several ways. Hence, its proof (here, below) could provide a solution for several similar puzzles.

Comment: @ProfessorVector do you want me to change the problem text rephrasing the question with something like "[...] Why is the expectation of this event infinite?"?

Comment: In that vein, and interesting case is flipping a fair coin.  The probability that the number of head equals the number of tails at some point is $1$, but the expected waiting time is $\infty$

Comment: Thank you again @saulspatz. Does this hold even for unfair coins?

Comment: I doubt it.  If heads is more likely, the difference between the number of heads and tails should tend to $\infty$.  I don't know what the probability that they're ever equal (after the first toss) is.  I suggest you try to work it out, and ask another question if you can't.

Comment: OK, thank you @saulspatz . I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just some back-of-the-envelope calculations, but I think they'll convince you that the probability that the event occurs is less than $1$, so that the expectation is infinite.

What is the probability that each number occurs $k$ times in $6k$ rolls?  There are $\frac{(6k)!}{(k!)^6}$ acceptable sequences of rolls out of $6^{6k}$ possible sequences so that the probability is $$\frac1{6^{6k}}\frac{(6k)!}{(k!)^6}$$  Stirling's approximation gives $$\frac1{6^{6k}}\frac{(6k)!}{(k!)^6}\sim\frac1{6^{6k}}\frac{(6k)^{6k}e^{-6k}\sqrt{12\pi k}}{(k^ke^{-k}\sqrt{2\pi k})^6}=\frac{\sqrt3}4(\pi k)^{-5/2}$$

Numerical calculation shows that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt3}4(\pi k)^{-5/2}\approx\frac1{30}$$

an this sequence overstates the probability, since it would count sequence where the phenomenon more than once multiple times.

This should convince you that doing the calculations carefully, if it were thought worthwhile, would demonstrate that the phenomenon is not very likely to occur, and that the expected waiting time until it does is infinite.

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz for the very simple and clear proof.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

Staring from @saulspatz's answer, I wonder what it would become for a fair $n$-sided die and worked in the same spirit
$$\frac1{n^{nk}}\frac{(nk)!}{(k!)^n}\sim \sqrt{n}\, (2 \pi )^{\frac{1-n}{2}} k^{\frac {1-n}2 }$$

$$P_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{nk}}\frac{(nk)!}{(k!)^n}\sim \sqrt{n}\, (2 \pi )^{\frac{1-n}{2}} \, \zeta \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)$$ which is almost a straight line in a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Thank you a lot @ClaudeLeibovici ! That's really interesting!